# sed for annoying text

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have following output:

```
    [root@localhost:~]# setkey -DP
    (per-socket policy)
            Policy:[Invalid direciton]
            created: Feb  5 09:25:06 2013  lastused: Feb  5 10:25:10 2013
            lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
            spid=411 seq=1 pid=4415
            refcnt=1
    (per-socket policy)
            Policy:[Invalid direciton]
            created: Feb  5 09:25:06 2013  lastused: Feb  5 10:13:21 2013
            lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
            spid=420 seq=2 pid=4415
            refcnt=1
    192.168.111.0/24[any] 192.168.0.0/24[any] any
            out prio def ipsec
            esp/tunnel/94.243.123.241-89.28.12.86/require
            created: Feb  5 09:25:13 2013  lastused: Feb  5 09:25:44 2013
            lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
            spid=441 seq=3 pid=4415
            refcnt=1
    192.168.0.0/24[any] 192.168.111.0/24[any] any
            in prio def ipsec
            esp/tunnel/89.28.12.86-94.243.123.241/require
            created: Feb  5 09:25:13 2013  lastused:
            lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
            spid=448 seq=4 pid=4415
            refcnt=1
    192.168.0.0/24[any] 192.168.111.0/24[any] any
            fwd prio def ipsec
            esp/tunnel/89.28.12.86-94.243.123.241/require
            created: Feb  5 09:25:13 2013  lastused:
            lifetime: 0(s) validtime: 0(s)
            spid=458 seq=0 pid=4415
            refcnt=1
```

and I want to get from it only this line:

```
    192.168.111.0/24 192.168.0.0/24
```

without any knowledge about it row's placement

I have made following regexp construction, but them don't work:

```
    [root@localhost:~]# setkey -DP | sed -rne 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(\/[0-9]{1,2}).*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(\/[0-9]{1,2})/\1\2\3\4/p'
    192.168.111.0111./242.168.0.0[any] any
    192.168.0.00./242.168.111.0[any] any
    192.168.0.00./242.168.111.0[any] any

    [root@localhost:~]# setkey -DP | sed -rne 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}).*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2})/\1\2/p'
    192.168.111.0/24111.[any] any
    192.168.0.0/240.[any] any
    192.168.0.0/240.[any] any
```

Where are the errors?

Thank you in advance, Evgheni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather find each group of number separately, something like this maybe:

```
sed -rn 's|[^0-9]*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,2})|\1\n|g; s/\n[^\n]*$//; s/\n/ /gp'
```

Output:

```
192.168.111.0/24 192.168.0.0/24
192.168.0.0/24 192.168.111.0/24
192.168.0.0/24 192.168.111.0/24
```

However, if you want to match the pair of groups, you may change your second regex into this:

```
sed -rne 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2})[^0-9]*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}).*/\1 \3/p'
```

1. Use a negation group `[^0-9]*` to do non-greedy matching between the number groups.
2. Add `.*` at the end to match everything after the number groups.
3. You want to replace everything with the first and third backreference (`\1` and `\3`). Backreferences are numbered based on the position of their starting parenthesis.

Comment: Great decision, I found my errors. Thank you for full explanation.

Comment: sorry for disturbing, but how will be better to take only first or second of match without using pipe. Changing **p** on **q** in expression doesn't work (

Comment: Want to find an alternative for  `setkey -DP | sed -rne 's/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2})[^0-9]*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}).*/\1 \3/p' | sed q`  `192.168.111.0/24 192.168.0.0/24`

Comment: @EvgheniAntropov: To get the first element use `\1` in the replacement part and `\3` for the second element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to get first line from all part of output, but do it in unique sed.

Comment: @EvgheniAntropov: ok I misunderstood your question. You can do this with the `t` command which branches if the last substitute command was successful: `sed 's/.../.../; t a; b; :a; p; q'`.

Comment: A cleaner way would be to use match instead of substitute: `sed -rne '/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2})[^0-9]*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]{1,2}).*/ { s//\1 \3/; p; q }'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use `sed`, then Thors answer should suffice. However, assuming you're after the first pattern match in your file, you could simply use `grep` and `xargs`:

```
< file grep -m 1 -oE "([0-9]{1,3}[\./]){4}[0-9]{1,2}" | xargs -n 2
```

Results:

```
192.168.111.0/24 192.168.0.0/24
```

If you are after all matches, drop the `-m 1` flag. HTH.

Comment: Thank you man, I don't want to use grep + xargs, cause of busybox using, but your expression working well: `setkey -DP | grep -m 1 -oE "([0-9]{1,3}[\./]){4}[0-9]{1,2}" | busybox xargs -n 2
192.168.111.0/24 192.168.0.0/24
`